# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException(Error on create tables in JPA )

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jpa

I'm trying create my first project in Java Jpa,but I found one problem when I create a table in JPA, when i click in Schema Generation on Eclipse and change to create in database action,shows:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

I haven't found any problem in my log, would someone help me?
I tried to change my  mysqlconnector, but no changes....

```
INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYMETRICS0001: Activating Eclipse MicroProfile Metrics Subsystem
INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 2.0.15.Final starting
INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
INFO  [io.smallrye.metrics] (MSC service thread 1-3) Converted [2] config entries and added [4] replacements
INFO  [io.smallrye.metrics] (MSC service thread 1-3) Converted [3] config entries and added [18] replacements



16:44:14,517 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'Loucademia.war#Loucademia
```

I didn't find any problem in my log, I don't know what is the problem in create table in JAVA JPA